# JavaScript: Merging two dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, merge, html5-audio, playlist

I have two dropdown menus that I want to merge in one, so the output would look like:
[image]

Which means the user can choose `From`: Numbers or Letters, and then `To` is connected to the first choice in each menu.

I tried different ways to merge with no luck.  There are two different JavaScripts involved, so I am not sure how to start in merging.

1- play (from/to): https://jsfiddle.net/d5g8w4cn/2/

2- the connected menus: http://jsfiddle.net/2pza5/

Answer (score 0):

To do this you'd probably need to programatically set your drop-down options in JS. So instead of hard coding each `<option />` element, create some data in JS and render your options based off of said data. This will enable you to manipulate the options and render them however you like - or at least make it easier than trying to do this from an HTML starting point.